# how to fix UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: unexpected end of data. i am using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am trying to preprocess the text data i got an error Unicode Decode Error .i am using python 2.7 please help me

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
def word_lemmatizer(data):
    lem_text = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in data]
    return lem_text
data['feedbackComment']=data['feedbackComment'].apply(lambda x:word_lemmatizer(x))
print data

error message
test.py:32: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  words = [w for w in data if w not in stopwords.words('english')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 49, in <module>
    data['feedbackComment']=data['feedbackComment'].apply(lambda x:word_lemmatizer(x))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2551, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1521, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "test.py", line 49, in <lambda>
    data['feedbackComment']=data['feedbackComment'].apply(lambda x:word_lemmatizer(x))
  File "test.py", line 45, in word_lemmatizer
    lem_text = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in data]
  File "/home/akhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/stem/wordnet.py", line 41, in lemmatize
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
  File "/home/akhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1909, in _morphy
    forms = apply_rules([form])
  File "/home/akhil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1889, in apply_rules
    if form.endswith(old)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Comment: Please post a constructive question. What you want to do, your codes and results (errors) etc.

Comment: I am trying to preprocess the text data